# Convert from PFX certificate to separate PEM files bypassing user input

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I need to call these **openssl** commands:

1. `openssl pkcs12 -in mycert.pfx -out mycert.pem`

   Enter a password and a passphrase twice.  --> I want to automate this!
2. `openssl pkcs12 -in mycert.pfx -out ca.pem -cacerts -nokeys`

   Enter a password  --> To automate
3. `openssl pkcs12 -in mycert.pfx -out client.pem -clcerts -nokeys`

   Enter a password  --> To automate
4. `openssl pkcs12 -in mycert.pfx -out key.pem -nocerts`

   Enter a password and a passphrase twice --> To automate

These commands will be called from a web server process in order to make the request below, including the PEM files:

```
curl -k https://www.apisite.com/endpoint -v –key key.pem –cacert ca.pem –cert client.pem
```

I will do it using PHP, like so:

```
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, 'client.pem');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, 'key.pem');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'ca.pem');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, $password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlStr); // e-invoice
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8')); 
    $resp = curl_exec($ch);
```

Is there anything I could do in order to bypass the user input and automate everything?

The PFX certificate is previously provided by the user and stored alongside the password. It must be PFX. The passphrase could be empty. Therefore no user input is needed while the operation, and as far as I know, I cannot use cURL with a PFX certificate. Hence the conversion. We need to provide this functionality to our users because we offer and invoicing system and they must deliver signed electronic invoices through https with their credentials to a tax agency.